# MS Word : Many eps images => very large file

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, eps

I have a word file (`.docx`) of ~10 pages with many `.eps` figures included. The .docx is very big (`145Mo`). Microsoft Word fails to save it as a pdf. I can print it. I can export it with [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) but the resulting images have a poor quality. I have tried a few options of [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) without much success.

Any idea of a fix?

Comment: What happens if you split the document into individual pages and save each page as a PDF?

Comment: You could also try with OpenOffice or LibreOffice.

Comment: @DavidPostill : it fails on page 7

Comment: @DavidPostill : with openoffice, the images are not correctly handled and it takes 1.8Go of memory to open the document

Comment: Did you try openoffice with just the page 7 in the document?

Comment: Hve you tried converting the eps images into another image format?

Comment: The quality problems will remain even if you manage to get Office to save the document as a PDF because of how that feature works.  Have you considered breaking up the document, into smaller chucks, Word does all the conversion in memory which is the reason is having a problem although 145Mb isn't that large.

Comment: @DavidPostill : openoffice does not handle correctly any of the .eps figures inserted in the .docx. Workaround is to use .png / .jpg files but they have a lower quality compared to .eps

Comment: @Ramhound : I was able to save as a pdf a 4 pages (24Mo) docx file. Quality of the pictures was perfect and obtained pdf was 3Mo